# Is System.currentTimeMillis() monotonic in the context of Java Memory Model?

Tags: java, java-memory-model, time-measurement

Is there a guarantee, that if one `System.currentTimeMillis()` call *happens before* another `System.currentTimeMillis()` call (from another thread), the value returned from the second call is not less than the value returned from the first call?

Comment: No.  However the memory model is not the cause of the non-monotonicity.  See linked Q&A.